# Calling Papa.parse in worker with _config.worker = false calls postMessage

Tags: javascript, web-worker, papaparse, worker-loader

I am calling `Papa.parse` in my own worker and in `_config.worker` is set false. 
When process completes it calls `postMessage` still that triggers a message to my own worker.
Shouldn't [this](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/papaparse.js#L529)

```
if (IS_PAPA_WORKER)
{
    global.postMessage({
        results: results,
        workerId: Papa.WORKER_ID,
        finished: finishedIncludingPreview
    });
}
```

Should also check if `config.worker` is set to `true` then only call `global.postMessage`
I don't want to send results to main thread any idea how can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do [define `IS_PAPA_WORKER`](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/papaparse.js#L56) to

```
var IS_WORKER = !global.document && !!global.postMessage,
    IS_PAPA_WORKER = IS_WORKER && /blob:/i.test((global.location || {}).protocol);
```

This means they do check is there is no `document` property, a `postMessage` property, and if the current realm has been loaded from a `blob:` URI.

The best solution in your case is probably to not load your script from a `blob:` URI, but instead use a dedicated script file.

```
const worker = new Worker( '/a_real_file.js' );
```

Here is a demo using a `data:` URI, since StackSnippets don't allow storage of files, but don't use `data:` URIs yourself, it's just for demo the protocol matters:

```js
const worker_script = document.querySelector( '[type="worker-script"]' ).textContent;
const worker_url = 'data:text/javascript,' + encodeURIComponent( worker_script );
const worker = new Worker( worker_url );
worker.onmessage = ({data}) => console.log( data );
worker.onerror = console.error;
```

```html
<script type="worker-script">
  importScripts( 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js' );
  
  const csv = `col1,col2,col3
a,1,z
b,2,y
c,3,x`;
  Papa.parse( csv, { header: true } );
  postMessage( 'worker done' );
</script>
```

Now if you absolutely need to use a `blob:` URI, the simplest solution is to define  `document` as a truthy global property before you import the library:

```js
const worker_script = document.querySelector('[type="worker-script"]').textContent;
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ worker_script ], { type: 'text/javascript' } ) );
const worker = new Worker( worker_url );
worker.onmessage = ({data}) => console.log( data );
```

```html
<script type="worker-script">
  self.document = {};
  importScripts( 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js' );
  
  const csv = `col1,col2,col3
a,1,z
b,2,y
c,3,x`;
  Papa.parse( csv, { header: true } );
  postMessage( 'worker done' );
</script>
```

Comment: Workes. I didn't check `worker-loader` inline will import it as a blob. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Who is using `worker-loader` in `webapck` don't use inline import

`this.worker = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "MyWorker" */ 'workers/MyWorker')` [this import it as BLOB](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader#inline)

import it using `import MyWorker from 'worker-loader!./MyWorker.js';` this imports it as file and won't cause issue.